# iframes are stripped from RichHTMLField

Tags: 2013, master-page, publishing-site

I have the HTML Field Security setting to allow iframes from youtube. However, when I add a youtube iframe to a RichHTMLField, it gets stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

When editing a HTML field, there is now a new button available on the ribbon called "Embed Code" in the "Insert" tab. As the  code is inserted, the dialog tells you that the content will be inserted in a web part. YouTube didn’t work because they prevent display in an iframe due to security reasons but Bing did.

If you need to open youtube, add content editor on page,click edit source and add below:

```
 <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hyRLzUVw4Vw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: well i know it is possible to have an iframe in the content box without embedding the code via button or a web part.